# Handle database error when using connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, express, connect, connect-mongo

I've got a fairly standard connect-mongo setup

*mongoose is initialised / connected prior to this*

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: "sfdgsdgsdfg",
    store: new MongoSessionStore({db: mongoose.connection.db})
}));
```

This works fine.

However -
Assuming my mongodb connection suddenly dies (stop mongod locally in the example below)
 - the next time I try to hit a route, my express app crashes too -

> Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
>       at null. (/Users/alex/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
>       at emit (events.js:106:17)
>       at null. (/Users/alex/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
>       at emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Socket. (/Users/alex/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at net.js:440:14
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

Is there a way to handle this error and (For example) redirect to a /error route?
(Obviously one that doesn't require session!)

**EDIT**

So now, I'm creating a separate mongoose connection.

I then use the `on('error'` to listen for errors

...this is where I'm getting stuck -
The process still dies because re-throwing the err doesn't pass it into the express error handler...

```
var sessionDbConnection = mongoose.createConnection(config.sessionDb);

sessionDbConnection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('oops');
    throw err; //instead of re-throwing the error, i think i need to pass it to the error handler below??
})

app.use(express.session({
    secret: "sfdgsdgsdfg",
    store: new MongoSessionStore({db: sessionDbConnection.db})
}));

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', err); //just for testing
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a general error handler at the end of your using chain ...

```
//function must accept 4 arguments
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  //use accepts to determin if you should return json, html, image?
  //render the appropriate output.
});
```

Also, have your handlers and other modules accept three parameters `(req, res, next)` in the case of an error, `return next(err)` typically you will want to optionally use a `.code` property to match up your http response code to the one matching the error.  using `4xx` for input errors, `5xx` for server errors etc.

Also, if you want to handle the general case...

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.error('Caught exception: ' + err);
  console.error(err.stack);

  //interrogate the error, if it's something you can recover from, let it be.
  //if the exception is fatal, exit with prejudice
  setTimeout(process.exit.bind(process, 666), 1000); //exit in a second
});
```

This will handle your specific case, but you should only allow the process to keep running if its' something that *should* recover on its' own.

---

In response to your edit... you could have a global variable that changes when you get a DB error... unfortunately, this error doesn't necessarily happen in the context of an http request.. it could happen before/during/after ... in this way, you cannot know.

If you are using a client that will re-connect on failure, then that will alleviate some issues.  The best you can do, is keep track of this variable, serve errors to all requests.. then restart your process.

There are lots of modules from `pm2` to `forever` that will help you with this.

Comment: I've got that error handler - however it doesn't seem to get 'hit' - it's like the error happens outside of express, and express can't do anything about it (it's the connect-mongo bit)

Comment: ... in fact, if I kill mongod - the process dies (with error shown in original post) before I even refresh page / visit another page

Comment: is your error handler registered after your mongo session store module?  it seems to me it's a bug in the module.

Comment: see my edit - i have included the error handler (after the module)